# Where is the maven dependency for ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory?

Tags: java, spring, maven, ssl, spring-boot

I am trying to follow this example for [setting up SSL with Tomcat in Spring Boot](https://gist.github.com/SlyDen/9408539). The example is unfortunately missing the import statements, so I tried to infer the correct import statement for [ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html).

However, I still encounter the following error:
The import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory cannot be resolved

I think this means I am missing the maven dependency for this particular class. Can anyone point me to what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from code for file package is `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded`

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How does the spring-boot artifact relate to spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-parent? Should it be in addition to these, or replace one or both?